# Is there anyway to have a if constexpr in expression?

Tags: c++

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements, I know I can express condition in C++ by at least the following two ways:

1. An if statement

   ```
   if (a) { b } else { c }
   ```
2. An [expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions) statement

   ```
   a ? b : c
   ```

And we have constexpr for if

```
if constexpr (a) { b } else { c }
```

Since in some area, we can only use expression statement for conditions, to avoid getting a "error: expected expression". So I write

```
cond ? call_func(), 0 : 0
```

However, how can we involve constexpr this in expression statement? This is a real problem, consider

```
template <int FLAG>
void f() {
    SOME_MACRO_ONLY_ALLOW_EXPRS({ FLAG ? call_func(), 0 : 0; })
}
```

I know I can specialize `f` for `FLAG=1` and `FLAG=0`. However, it may involves lots of modification.

Comment: ITYM `cond ? (call_func(), 0) : 0`

Comment: There's always the immediate-lambda trick `[&]{ if constexpr(a) return b; else return c; }();`. Both the lambda definition and calling the lambda are expressions.